# Issues with subbing PHP variables into a HTML form field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having an issue with inputting data stored in a PHP variable into a HTML form, using the value property in the  tag. The problem seems to be that strings are being cut around spaces, where only the first part of the string before the space making it to the form. Strings without spaces appear with a forward slash at the end.

The idea for the form is that a customer could edit the details store about them on a MySQL database, and then changing the values with an update statement. So it's really important that the values appear as they are stored in the PHP variables.

Example:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pvfYApy.png]

```
<?php
//session start//
session_start();

//Connect to the server and database//
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","mia");

//Generate the sql statement for retrieval of customer details//
$customerdetails="SELECT Name, BusinessName, Address, Postcode, TelNo, Email
                  FROM customer
                  WHERE CustomerID = " . $_SESSION['CustomerID'] . "";

//execute the 'Customer details retrieve' sql statement//
$result= mysqli_query($con, $customerdetails);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $Name='' . $row['Name'] . '';
        $BusinessName=$row['BusinessName'];
        $Addresss=$row['Address'];
        $Postcode=$row['Postcode'];
        $TelNo=$row['TelNo'];
        $Email=$row['Email'];
    }

//Write the web page//
echo "<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Edit Details
</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Edit Details</h1>
<p>Please change values below where apropriate</p>
<form name='input'
          action='../php/update_customer.php'
          method='post'>
        Name:           <input type='string'
                               name='Name' value=" . $Name ."/> </br>
        Business Name:  <input type='text'
                               name='BusinessName' value=" . $BusinessName ."/> </br>
        Address:        <input type='text'
                               name='Address' value=" . $Addresss ."/> </br>                       
        Post Code:      <input type='text'
                               name='Postcode' value=" . $Postcode ."/> </br>
        Telephone No:   <input type='text'
                               name='TelNo' value=" . $TelNo ."/> </br>
        Email Address:  <input type='text'
                               name='Email' value=" . $Email ."/> </br>
        <input type='submit'   value='Update'/>
    </form>

<p>" . $Name . "</p>
<p>" . $_SESSION['CustomerID'] . "</p>
</body>
</html>";

?>
```

Comment: You mean aside from your HTML injection problem? Consider a `Name` value of `Bob"><script>alert('gotcha')</script><input type='text' value="`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing quotes around your value. You should do add quotes like this:

```
<input type='text' name='Name' value='" . $Name ."'/>
```

Note the single quote before the first double quote and after the second.

Another issue is that you are using an invalid type. `string` is no valid input type, it should be text.

Your biggest issue might be you are fetching an array, then looping over it and in every iteration you overwrite all your variables that you are later using in your form. Therefore you will always get the names, addresses, etcetera for the last record you find in your database.

Unless you escape your values before inserting them into the database, you should also make sure they don't contain any special html characters. You can escape special characters like this:

```
$Name = htmlspecialchars($row['Name']);
$BusinessName = htmlspecialchars($row['BusinessName']);
$Addresss = htmlspecialchars($row['Address']);
$Postcode = htmlspecialchars($row['Postcode']);
$TelNo = htmlspecialchars($row['TelNo']);
$Email = htmlspecialchars($row['Email']);
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Thank you so much, I started with PHP yesterday, and my teacher seems to be as experienced as I am. He couldn't help me, and I have been struggling with this all day. Fixed the while loop also, but it was the only was I was taught to call multiple values from an array, and this way makes much more sense to me.

Comment: If you are certain you are only getting back one row, you could also fetch one row only, or access the first row only by using something like `$resultarray[0]['Name']`. Also note my edit about escaping the output of your variables. Also, please accept the answer if this solved your problem. That way others can quickly see your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to close the `value` into apostrophes like so:

```
<input type='string' name='Name' value='" . $Name ."' />
```

And you should escape apostrophes *and any other characters that have special significance in HTML* from the string before you're printing it as well using [**`htmlspecialchars`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
$Name = htmlspecialchars($Name);
```

Also, looping when fetching the data from the database is unnecessary assuming `CustomerID` is unique.

Comment: Please use the `htmlspecialchars` function for character escaping. That way you are sure all unwanted characters are escpaped.

Comment: @PatrickKostjens - Yes, of course. I almost forgot there is such a function, what was I thinking of? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Make space the end tag of textbox

```
<input type='text' name='TelNo' value=" . $TelNo ." /> </br>
```

Also email address.

Otherwise add single quotes(')

```
<input type='text' name='TelNo' value='" . $TelNo ."'/> </br>
```